# org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process null

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to run test for my app and I'm using Maven, testng, java. When I run tests from command line (`_mvn clean test site -PRunUITestsProfile -Dgroups=Group1_`) everything works fine.

However when I try to run the same tests on jenkins I get the error:

> There was an error in the forked process null
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There
>   was an error in the forked process null

I tried to use different versions of testng (`6.14.3 - 7.0.0-beta4`) and surefire plugin (`2.19 - 3.0.0-M3`) which didn't help

**Full error message**

```
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
null
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:657)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:283)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:246)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1149)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:991)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:837)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

**My pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.any23</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-any23-csvutils</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gitlab4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>gitlab4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.18</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>RunSetupProfile</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/suits/setup.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <argLine>
                            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                        </argLine>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>RunUITestsProfile</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/suits/UI_suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <argLine>
                             -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                        </argLine>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>RunSmokeUITestsProfile</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/suits/Smoke_UI_suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <argLine>
                            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                        </argLine>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>RunPerfTestsProfile</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/suits/perf_suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                                <value>false</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>listener</name>
                                <value>org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Looks like a NullPointerException in static code. try to run the maven with option -X for more informations

Answer (score 3):

Well... after spending some more time trying to figure out what the heck is wrong, I migrated to Gradle, where everything works fine now...

Comment: Hi  Jake , Are you working on Development project or Automation Testing.

Comment: I am working on testing side where i faced the same issue while running on Automation suite using java Selenium + cucumber + Testng. If you have solutions can please shed some light here as i am completely stuck with this issue